# Testing parameter significance vs model fit

Tags: panel-data, structural-equation-modeling, mediation, lavaan

In one of our studies we test a mediation hypothesis in a longitudinal (it's actually panel data) study with 4 measurement waves.

We test a setup similar to one outlined by Cole & Maxwell (2003) for 
longitudinal mediation analysis. We find the hypothesized indirect effects. But the model as a whole doesn't fit too well (according to CFA, RMSEA, and so on).

The fit problem comes from the fact that variables in waves 3 and 4 are 
predicted not only by their lagged values in the immediately previous wave, but by even earlier lagged waves. So, for example, the model is specified so that Y at T4 is predicted only by Y at T3 (this is the standard 
specification), but it turns out that Y at T4 is also affected by 
Y at T1 and T2 and that Y at T3 is also affected by Y 
at T1

When we add those effects into the model (following modificationIndices in `lavaan()` the hypothesized indirect effect get 
insignificant and the model is difficult to interpret.

- In terms of observational and experimental research results is there
  any solution to this situation accepted in the literature?  For
  example: accepting low fit, but showing what was hypothesized?
- Also relevant, tested predictor and mediator are trait-like - and
  pretty static. Could this be a reason why we get those effects?

Comment: Don't accept poor fit. This is tell you that your model is wrong, and the parameter estimates are not trustworthy.

Comment: Yes, this is an effect that you get if  a measure is essentially stable and measured with error. Changes aren't real, they're random noise.